# Скроллинг страницы с lazy load

Tags: javascript, прокрутка, lazyloading

У меня есть страница с товарами, на неё сразу выводится 12 товаров, а потом когда страница проскроллилась до конца, скрипт обращается к PHP, передает ему стартовую точку(12, тк уже загружено 12), и по ней PHP ищет следующие товары и возвращает их в JS? который их вставляет в документ. Те это ленивая загрузка.

Можно нажать на товар(откроется окно с товаром), можно перейти в другую вкладку сайта и тп операции. Прежде чем это сделать я сохраняю в `localStorage` `main.scrollTop`, а потом мне нужно когда пользователь возвращается на главную страницу с товарами прокрутить страницу до места, где пользователь остановился.

Вариант с полной прокруткой от самого начала до места, где остановился пользователь, меня не особо устраивает, тк придется повторно загрузить все товары, который пользователь уже посмотрел. А если он посмотрел штук 500, 1000 товаров?

Желательно сделать, чтобы товары вверху либо остались загруженными, либо их там не было вообще, а когда пользователь скроллит вверх, их уже тогда загрузить

Не подскажите ли как это реализовать?

Comment: странно ,что за целый день никто еще не ответил...

Comment: Открывайте в таком случае товары в виде модальных окон (поверх основного контента), либо в новой вкладке.